# JavaScript map returning array of objects instead of ojbect

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Javascript method returns array of object instead of object.

**Helper method:**

```
export const getDefaultValue = (valueList) => {
    return defaultValue = valueList.map((item, index) => {
        if (item.isDefault) {
            return item;
        }
    });
}
```

**Input:**

```
let valueList = [{itemId: 1, isDefault: true}, {itemId: 2, isDefault: false}, {itemId: 3, isDefault: false}]
```

When calling `getDefaultValue(valueList)`, I'm getting below output:

**Output:**

```
[{itemId: 1, isDefault: true}, undefined, undefined]
```

Shouldn't `getDefaultValue` return only `{itemId: 1, isDefault: true}`?

Newbie to `JavaScript`. What am I missing here?

Comment: From the documentation on [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): _"creates **a new array** with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array."_ - Should have been part of your research.

Comment: do you want only one element or all which where `isDefault` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)?

Comment: Only the element.

Comment: `.map` creates a new array and **won't** stop on the first occurrence. You probably wanted to use `filter` instead, or, even better, `.find`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` isn't right for this - use `find`:

```
export const getDefaultValue = (valueList) => {
    return defaultValue = valueList.find((item, index) => {
        if (item.isDefault) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

You could also simplify it:

```
export const getDefaultValue = valueList => valueList.find(({ isDefault }) => isDefault);
```

Comment: find is only find the first item. did you mean filter?

Comment: Nope. Look at the expected output.

Comment: yep. wants an object not an array with isDefault:true criteria.

Comment: And that's exactly what my answer does @MuratAras - your point is?

Answer (score 2):

You need to filter the array with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and this returns either the element or not, depending on the return value.

```
return defaultValue = valueList.filter(item => item.isDefault);
```

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new element for each element.

---

**After** a clear problem description, you need to take [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for getting a single object.

This method returnd the first found element or `undefined` if not element fullfills the condition.

```
return defaultValue = valueList.find(item => item.isDefault);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you just want to get the one matching value from the array, you should use `.find` instead:

```
export const getDefaultValue = (valueList) => {
    return defaultValue = valueList.find((item) => {
        if (item.isDefault) {
            return true;
        }
    });
};
```

`.map` will always construct a new array, based on all items of the old array, which isn't what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

The Array.Map() method returns array of values. Since you are returning item itself which is an object, the final output becomes array of object.

try this:

```
 export const getDefaultValue = (valueList) => {
    return defaultValue = valueList.map((item, index) => {
        if (item.isDefault) {
            return item.itemId;
        }
    });
}
```

which will also capture undefined if nothing gets returned. You can you filter method instead.

```
const  getDefaultValue = valueList.filter(item => item.isDefault);
```